# Inner automorphisms of Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

I have a few questions about $Aut(G)$, when $G$ is a Lie group. It was proven by Hochschild that if $G/G_0$ is finitely generated, then $Aut(G)$ is a Lie group with at most countably many components.

With $G_0$ I mean the component connected to the identity which is normal. 
I would like to ask?

> What are the identity components of $Aut(G)$ and $Aut(G_0)$?
>   Let's call them $Aut_0(G)$ and $Aut_0(G_0)$.

Moreover:

> Is there a relation between $Aut_0(G)$ (or $Aut_0(G_0)$), and $Inn(G)$ (or $Inn(G_0)$)? Under which hypotheses?

And since they are both normal:

> Is there a relation between $Aut(G)/Aut_0(G)$ and $Out(G)$? (Same for $G_0$.)

Last question:

> Are there any relations like the ones I asked above, but between the Lie algebras?

Any insight is appreciated, sources and references are very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by «what are the components of Aut(G) connected to the identity?»

Comment: he/she meant "identity components".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Edited, thanks to both.

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. What sort of answer do you expect for the question «what are the components of Aut(G)?» They are the components of Aut(G)...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I mean, what can we say about them, in general? Are they linked to some homotopy properties of $G$, for example?